# Timeout feature in Axios has no effect in a NativeScript(-Vue) environment

Tags: android, axios, nativescript

I have a Nativescript-Vue project built with `vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template` using the axios library.

If I run the following snippet in a browser environment, it works fine, that is, times out as expected with such a short timeout setting:

```
    const apiClient = axios.create({
      timeout: 1,
    })

    apiClient.request({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    }).then(response => {
      console.log('this.apiClient.defaults.timeout', apiClient.defaults.timeout)
      console.log(response.config)
      console.log(response.data)
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
```

However, when I run the code in a NativeScript-Vue project on Android, the request completes as if there were no timeout setting present at all. Even though you can see from the console.logs that the value for timeout is 1.

If I make a similar request with NativeScript's "http/http-request" module, the timeout setting is respected as expected.

[Update:]

Turned out that Manoj's workaround below alone wasn't sufficient for our requirements because only connect timeout is set for the HttpURLConnection in [org.nativescript.widgets.Async's HttpRequestTask](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/8d382a6b2e722e9298becdcfb3b43a41352a9136/tns-core-modules-widgets/android/widgets/src/main/java/org/nativescript/widgets/Async.java#L527). Setting read timeout provided the desired result, that is, causing the timeout to expire when no data is received within the timeout period. So, [I suggested](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6523) considering setting read timeout in addition to connect timeout:

```
// apply timeout
if (options.timeout > 0)
{
  connection.setConnectTimeout(options.timeout);
  connection.setReadTimeout(options.timeout);
}
```

Comment: What values are in the response? The catch does not get called?

Comment: The response data is just a simple object, eg.
`{  "userId": 1,  "id": 1,   "title": "delectus aut autem",  "completed": false }`

Yes, the catch doesn't get called because the request succeeds instead of timing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's not implemented in the XHR wrapper (as of v6.2.0) but only in the original http request class. Try adding the code below in your `app.js`.

```
import { XMLHttpRequest } from 'tns-core-modules/xhr';
import * as types from "tns-core-modules/utils/types";

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.originalSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
    if (types.isDefined(this._options) && types.isNumber(this.timeout)) {
        this._options.timeout = this.timeout;
    }
    this.originalSend(data);
};
```

You might want to submit a issue at Github.

Comment: Tried adding your suggestion. The function gets called but `this.timeout` is `undefined`.

Comment: `timeout` should be valid only if you set it on Axios. If you have issues kindly share a Playground sample to test.

Comment: Here's a playground https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=hAc6cD
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Axios sets timeout after open method is called. So overridden the send method which seems to do the job. [Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=hAc6cD&v=2)